# sql database is empty

Tags: python, mysql

My program is in python flask application into a MySQL database. On my website, I am doing the proper procedures; however, the database says it has no rows. It's empty.

```
demo = request.form.get("demo")
id= session["user_id"]
cheese = request.form.get("cheese")
table_update = db.execute("UPDATE usertable SET cheese = '1' WHERE id= :id", id=id)
```

cheese has a value of "on", because it's a radio in HTML forms

demo has a value of text

When I hit submit on my HTML form, it doesn't store the values in the sql database.

Comment: maybe you get error message in console?

Comment: no, there were no error messages.

Comment: did you display `cheese` ? did you check rows directly in database ? did you try your SQL query directly in database ?

Comment: db.commit() after db.execute().

Comment: I used a print function (like print(cheese)) and confirmed the value was 'on' when the proper action took place. I have checked rows directly in the database,

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that user_id did not have primary key. I don't know how it worked but it did.